htaccess tips on hide all GET parameters
I would like some advice on how to "hide" all the GET variables inside the htaccess file for example:
https://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?r=<something>&n=<something else>&z=<something more>

I would like all the GET parameters to be "hidden".
I know this can be done, I tried some solutions but without success.
for example:
https://www.mywebsite.com/customers
https://www.mywebsite.com/users
https://www.mywebsite.com/invoices

Thank you all

Sounds like you are asking how URL rewriting works in general, so please go and consult Reference: mod_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained. You can ask here again, if you run into problems, or have specific questions.

In addition to what @C3roe suggests one thing you should understand: you can not somehow magically "hide" those parameters. If they are not present in the URL then there is no logic on the server side that can guess those values. What you can do is format the URL different. That's all.
